# Protools 9 sync bug?

Tags: pro-tools, bugs

Hi folks

I've had the same problem with PT9 as some of you had, when sending the mix back
to the editor, everything was grossly out of sync, so i had to go back to PT8.

Does anybody know if there was an update already to fix this? Its been a while....

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds from your comment that you may have fallen victim to a pulldown enabled within the PT engine on one of the machines.  I've seen this often-overlooked setting wreck havock on a session, and your sync drift mention leads me directly to this conclusion.  Disable the pulldown (or pullup, whichever it is), and that should solve the problem hopefully.

If not, I'm very certain that the problem is at least focused on a pulldown/pullup issue, or a famerate mismatch is some sort.  These are the two 'staples' which generate sync drifting issues.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! The framerates were matched, the pulldown/up thing i did overlook when going to pt9, as i just assumed it didn't have the option not being HD and all, stupidly so, i'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

"grossly out of sync"

what does that mean exactly? The first two things to check are: 
1. was the 2pop at the head in sync?
2. was the 2pop at the tail in sync?

If you don't have a SMPTE leader with 2 pop on the head and tail of the QT the editor provided then you must, for this very reason. We use PT9 and there are no sync issues with layback or negs for film mixes being out of sync. But the process has to be rock solid, because there are many, many ways that mistakes can be made that put things out of sync, and I don't mean solely by the sound post dept. - there can be picture conform errors, undocumented picture edits, late VFX sync changes etc.... Are you sure the QT you worked to matches the final picture?

Comment: Hi Tim, I've started editing at the studio i was interning at, in their pt8 hd rig, then i switched to my own pt9 in my laptop and everything was fine and dandy, when i sent the final mix back to the editor/director it started perfectly in sync and after 5 minutes things started to get up to 4 seconds out of sync. I've installed back pt8 to check what was up and indeed what played fine in PT9, in 8 was all screwed up.... Further reading in gearslutz and here, other people were having the same problem... What am i missing?! Thanks